# How to disable touch screen permanently on my Asus Notebook?

Tags: asus, touchscreen

I just installed Ubuntu on an old Asus notebook which already had Windows 10 installed. Then somehow, the screen got damaged and touchscreen began working on its own. I disabled the touchscreen drivers, and it worked. But while using the **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** on same Asus notebook the issue is back again. I tried to disable it using the following command on my terminal

`sudo modprobe -r hid_multitouch`

But after some time, the touchscreen stopped working again. Please suggest me to fix this issue.

Comment: Please be specific with details; you mention Ubuntu, but not which Ubuntu product. You also tagged *ubuntu-touch* which was a Ubuntu product, but is now Lomiri supported by UBports, so is this what you're asking about? as this isn't the correct site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but it may fixed by editing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf to :

`Section "InputClass" Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall" MatchIsTouchscreen "off" MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" #Driver "evdev" Option "Ignore" "on" EndSection`

And

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf to :

`Section "InputClass" Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall" MatchIsTouchscreen "off" MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" #Driver "libinput" Option "Ignore" "on" EndSection`

Comment: Yes, i did the same. Now, no ghost touch appears on my screen. `Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "off"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        EndSection`

Comment: So it worked ? Vote if it helped

Comment: It helped one of my customers thanks !